# Symfony2 doctrine2 working with collections - performances

Tags: performance, symfony, memory, collections, doctrine-orm

The point of this question is to figure out what technique is better and heard different opinions from some skilled symfony2 coders.

An example will be ilustrated on challenges and "challenge rating" table where many people can rate certain challenge. (something like stackoverflow vote question system).

The tables look like this: (like_dislike is boolean(1= like, 0 = dislike)

[image: Challenges table] [image: challenge rating table]

The amount of data will be from 10-200+  rates for challenge.

---

### Working with collections

***Challenges entity***

```
/**
 * Challanges
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="challanges")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\ChallangesRepository")
 */
class Challanges
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $start_date;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $end_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\UserBundle\Entity\User", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\ChallangeRating", mappedBy="challange", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $likes;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->likes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Add likes
 *
 * @param \TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\ChallangeRating $likes
 * @return Challanges
 */
public function addLike(\TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\ChallangeRating $likes)
{
    $this->likes[] = $likes;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove likes
 *
 * @param \TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\ChallangeRating $likes
 */
public function removeLike(\TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\ChallangeRating $likes)
{
    $this->likes->removeElement($likes);
}

/**
 * Get likes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getLikes()
{
    return $this->likes;
}

public function filterLikesInChallenge($like_dislike) {
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('like_dislike', $like_dislike));

    return $this->likes->matching($criteria);
}

public function checkIfUserRatedAlready(\TB\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('fan', $user));

    return $this->likes->matching($criteria);
}
```

***Challenge rating entity***

```
<?php

namespace TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ChallangeRating
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="challange_rating")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\ChallangeRatingRepository")
 */
class ChallangeRating
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="like_dislike", type="boolean")
     */
    private $like_dislike;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="fans")
     */
    protected $fan;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\Challanges", inversedBy="likes")
     */
    protected $challange;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get like_dislike
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getLikeDislike()
    {
        return $this->like_dislike;
    }

    /**
     * Set like_dislike
     *
     * @param boolean $like_dislike
     * @return ChallangeRating
     */
    public function setLikeDislike($like_dislike)
    {
        $this->like_dislike = $like_dislike;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set fan
     *
     * @param \TB\UserBundle\Entity\User $fan
     * @return ChallangeRating
     */
    public function setFan(\TB\UserBundle\Entity\User $fan = null)
    {
        $this->fan = $fan;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fan
     *
     * @return \TB\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getFan()
    {
        return $this->fan;
    }

    /**
     * Set challange
     *
     * @param \TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\Challanges $challange
     * @return ChallangeRating
     */
    public function setChallange(\TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\Challanges $challange = null)
    {
        $this->challange = $challange;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get challange
     *
     * @return \TB\ChallangesBundle\Entity\Challanges 
     */
    public function getChallange()
    {
        return $this->challange;
    }
}
```

---

Okay and now i would like:

1. Display challenge details
2. Display rate feature (like, dislike) also with numbers of likes and dislikes
3. Display the list of all users that have rated this challenge

***Controller***

So classic beginning with obtaining $challenge

```
// this will take care of point number 1 (display challenge details) (1.)
$challange = $challangesRepo->findOneBy(array('slug'=>$slug)); 

// display numbers of likes and dislikes for certain challenge (2.)
```

But now comes a decision...

### Question 1

*Should i obtain the likes via quering the DB from querybuilder? (classic select count)*

**OR**

*Should i use collections and criteria like this ? :*

```
    $challangeLikes = $challange->filterLikesInChallenge(1);
    $challangeDislikes = $challange->filterLikesInChallenge(0);
```

**What is better for memory usage? what is better for DB performances? **

If i am not wrong the following two queries are executed by these two methods:

```
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id1, 
  t0.like_dislike AS like_dislike2, 
  t0.fan_id AS fan_id3, 
  t0.challange_id AS challange_id4 
FROM 
  challange_rating t0 
WHERE 
  (
    t0.like_dislike = ? AND t0.challange_id = ? 
  )
Parameters: [1, 12] 

SELECT 
  t0.id AS id1, 
  t0.like_dislike AS like_dislike2, 
  t0.fan_id AS fan_id3, 
  t0.challange_id AS challange_id4 
FROM 
  challange_rating t0 
WHERE 
  (
    t0.like_dislike = ? AND t0.challange_id = ? 
  )
```

And now i can pass the number of likes,dislikes to the view as follow:

```
'challangeLikes'=>$challangeLikes->count(),
'challangeDislikes'=>$challangeDislikes->count(),
```

### Question 2

What if i want to know if certain user rated this challenge already?

Again...

*Should i use classic querybuilder style with select count *

**OR**

I should use a method like:

```
$ratedAlreadyCol = $challange->checkIfUserRatedAlready($user)->first();
```

That will execute actually another query ? something like classic select count but the collection will do this for me? So it's not a search in some big memory array with allll likes but it's a query to DB ?

```
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id1, 
  t0.like_dislike AS like_dislike2, 
  t0.fan_id AS fan_id3, 
  t0.challange_id AS challange_id4 
FROM 
  challange_rating t0 
WHERE 
  (
    t0.fan_id = ? AND t0.challange_id = ? 
  )
Parameters: [25, 12]
```

### Question 3 - probably the most important for performances

I want to display all "fans - people who rated the certain challenge"...

Again...

*Should i create a separate querybuilder method in repository with selecting all ratings for certain challenge with inner join to the users table (so i can display profile image and username)*

**OR**

Should i just get all ratings and in twig loop through it like:

```
 $challangeLikesCollection = $challange->getLikes();

{% for bla bla
```

### BUT

If i will do it this way... doctrine will execute a select query to the user table for every "fan" in loop... and when there will be let's say... 200 fans... that's not good right?

### BONUS QUESTION

Can somehow please provide his way of dealing with these situations? any suggestions?

Or do you use any other technique?

i care a lot about memory usage and DB load time because this will be used everywhere and every user will have such a list with different challenges. The list will consist of let's say 15 challenges and to connect all the likes,dislikes to every challenge in the list etc etc... performances...

Thank you for your explanations, tips and hints that will help me and other readers to move on another level!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Denormalize a little and add `number of likes` and `number of dislikes` fields to `Challenge` and update these values in `addLike` and `removeLike`
2. Rename `like_dislike` to `like` as it's a boolean field and 1 means like 0 means dislike
3. Query the list of users with a separate query and use array hydration and INDEXBY username (it must be unique or user id) or maybe create a custom hydrator

   SELECT u.username, u.photo FROM User u INNER JOIN u.ratings WITH r.fan = :fan INDEX BY u.username

   or something like that. And you can check if the current user's username is in the array or not.

I think this could be performant enough.

Some explanation:

[INDEX BY means](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by) that the result collection or array key (index) will be the value of a field (this field has to be unique). When you use INDEX BY the result set will contain known keys so you can reach (and e.g. check for existence) individual results directly in constant time (you don't have to search through the whole result set).

Doctrine uses PDO underneath, hydration means how the PDO result set will be processed and transformed into something else. The default object hydration means the result set will be transformed into an object graph, it is a very expensive operation. There are [other hydration modes](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes) which are less expensive, but you loose some felxibility. E.g. if you use array hydration the result will be an array of arrays so you can't modify it (I mean persist back to the database) so it's just for reading and as the result not entity objects you can't use it's methods, e.g. custom getters. You can create [custom hydrators](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) if you want.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! 1. i was playing with this idea before..it's good. 2. It's just a cosmetic change because my like_dislike is boolean as well. 3. Hmm i see so to select all fans for certain challenge you would create custom query that selects only the username and photo right? And one more question..."use array hydration and INDEXBY username" I never understood this "hydration word" what does it mean please? Could you explain it? And  why is there INDEX BY u.username? What it's it purpose? The query will select the data following " r.fan_id" or not? which is foreign key.Thx

Comment: I added some explanation... Yes you should select only the fields you need. Yes `r.fan` means fun_id but I'm not sure you can use fun_id directly, but correct the query if needed. (2. Yes it's cosmetic or rather readability e.g. what does like_dislike = 1 means? It means like or dislike? You don't know for sure. But the field called like, it's clear that like = 1 means like and like = 0 means dislike, but it's maybe just me...)

Comment: Hmm i think it's just you :D like_dislike work's gr8 for my logic :D but thx for tip hh. I marked your answer! I finally learn what the hydration is about heh... so in big sites to avoid memory problems i should use array hydration? And i did not know about INDEX BY and the KEYS in result! This will be veeery handy in future. Thank you a lot! i think my effort with question just paid off :) Thx! :)

Comment: It's just the first (and painless) step for performance... it has it's own limits too and you can't use array hydration if you want to make modifications on entities, but in your case it fits great. When it reaches it's limits than you can start using some sort of caching and/or other solutions like redis, but don't do premature optimization, you should deal with that when the time comes.

Comment: Yea i see... the hydration first (if it fits) as now. The caching is of course a big thing... i am working on one big project but i had problem with caching...and this is the next thing on my list what i am going to move on another lvl. Do you think you could help me please? Maybe for some $$$ ? :) or just via some tips on good articles/videos ? i have some experiences with caching of course like ESI, and classic         $query=$qb->getQuery();  
        $query->useResultCache(true,3600);
        $query->useQueryCache(true);
             
        return $query->getResult();

Comment: But i have only low understanding of it and i want to move it on another lvl :)